# How to check if the * .js file is JScript or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wsh, jscript

I want to use *.js file both: on local web page on my pc (as JavaScript) and as WSH JScript when I double click *.js file. Is it possible to write a code running on both platforms?

How to check is running JS file is JavaScript or Microsoft JScript?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
if (typeof(document) == "undefined")
    alert('WSH Script!');
    WScript.Quit;
}
else {
    document.writeln('Hello world');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How does the script you included fail? (Please edit your question to include any error messages or describe any incorrect behaviour.) I'm not familiar with WSH, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14450424/1175455) the `window` object isn't present in the WSH environment, so you might try checking for that.

Comment: My code returns this error:

`---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: D:\JS\plik js - oryg.js
Line: 4
Char: 1
Error: Syntax error
Code: 800A03EA
Source:  Microsoft JScript compilation error`

I'm wondering is there something like `tepeof` in JScript? Because it seams to be a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can check if `WScript` object exists e.g

   `if (typeof WScript === 'object')`
2. `Quit` is a function so you should call it, e.g

   `WScript.Quit();`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Good point with WScript.Quit();. alert() is also not recognized on JScript so I changed it

Now I changed the code to:

`if (typeof WScript === 'object') {
    WSHshell= WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WSHshell.Popup("WSH Script!")
    WScript.Quit();
}
else {
    document.writeln('Hello world');
}`

Now it runs as JScript very well, and on a web browser! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the right code (thanks to Sergii Vorobei):

```
if (typeof WScript === 'object') {
    WSHshell= WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WSHshell.Popup("WSH Script!")
    WScript.Quit();
}
else {
    document.writeln('Hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another nice trick using "conditional compilation":

```js
if (/*@cc_on !@*/0) {
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Hello from JScript");
} else {
    console.log('Hello from NodeJS');
}
```

more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24473897/4999991).